# How to use linux gpio subsystem with PySerial for RS485 DE signal (RTS)

Tags: pyserial, gpio, rs485

I'm using PySerial to communicate to some devices over RS485 multi-drop.  I am bit-banging the DE signal to enable transmission before sending a packet and releasing it at the end.

The problem is that the time for release varies, especially under processor load, and the responses from the devices get clobbered (and aren't received).

I know PySerial has RS485 support, but from everything I've read about my embedded SBC (NXP iMX6 Dual), the RTS signal is not available on the GPIO connector.  I just have arbitrary GPIO to use.

**Is there a way to map an arbitrary GPIO signal to the RTS functionality so that the Linux tty drivers will assert/deassert my desired GPIO pin?**

The following statement gives me some hope (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/driver-api/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.html)

"""
... there are special GPIO drivers in subsystems like ... the TTY serial subsystem to emulate MCTRL (modem control) signals CTS/RTS by using two GPIO lines.
"""

There seems to be some kind of support for in the tty driver for /dev/ttyimxN devices.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/drivers/tty/serial/serial_mctrl_gpio.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/drivers/tty/serial/imx.c

```
    unsigned int        have_rtsgpio:1;
```

**But how can I set this up with PySerial?**

**How can I specify the GPIO port to use (if at all)?**

Thanks for any help !!

**EDIT**

I've found info in the kernel sources that match the kernel on my board.  This describes how to specify the gpio for modem control emulation (software control, instead of hardware control).

https://github.com/ADVANTECH-Corp/linux-imx/blob/adv_4.14.98_2.0.0_ga/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/serial/serial.txt

So it seems possible by changing the device tree sources and making a new device tree blob for my system.

This should all be independent of pyserial.

I'm not sure if this can be set/overridden at runtime with an ioctl, which would be handy (instead of having to muck around with kernel sources and building device tree blobs, etc).

Comment: Yes, many serial drivers that support RS485 allow to use any GPIO as DE. You need latest kernel (better to start with v5.10-rc3).

Comment: Great !!  How is this achieved, setup, configured?

Comment: @0andriy Edited question with more info re setting gpio for modem control signals via devicetree.